# Hover parent div; show text in child div. Do not show text when hover child div

Tags: html, css

Very new to HTML and CSS. I've finally figured out how to hover a div and cause that to show text in another div. But what then happens is when I hover the div where the text appears that too shows the text; which I don't not want.

```
    <div class="leaf5">

    <img class="leaf-5-about" src="images/Leaf%205%20about.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/Leaf%205%20about%20hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/Leaf%205%20about.png'">

    <div class="cashdup-info">

        <h3 class="cashdup-text"><i><span style="font-size: 38px; color: #359869" >CashdUp</span> is a home budgeting tool that allows you to make every cent count. </i></h3>

    </div>

    </div>
```

Is there a way to hover the div called "leaf5" and have that show text in another div without the text showing up if I hover the actual div the text is contained in. My CSS is as follows:

```
.cashdup-text {
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 22px;
    display: none;    
}

.leaf5:hover .cashdup-text {
    display: block;        
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: try with java script.

Comment: Can you give `.leaf5` a predetermined height, or position `.cashdup-text` absolutely?

Answer (score 2):

```
.leaf5:hover .cashdup-text:hover {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

I wouldn't use `display: none` here, because an element that has `display: none` logically can't be in a hover state.

Comment: Should I use opacity: 0 and opacity: 1 instead?

Comment: visibility has better browser support than opacity, other than that you can use either.

Answer (score 0):

Use this way :

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Eauyu/119/)

[Demo for  single image only](http://jsfiddle.net/Eauyu/120/)

**CSS:**

```css
div {
  display: none;
}

img:hover + div {
  display: block;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<img src="image/imh.pmg">
<div>Stuff shown on hover</div>
```

Comment: But I haven't used an anchor tag. What I'm hovering on is an img, which is one of many on the page. The one I want to hover over is not a link.

Comment: then usey <img> tags instead of <a> tag it will work.

Comment: Will this cause all of img tags to show the text though when they are hovered over?

Comment: i update my answer for all image  i provide the code for  single image i gave the link .

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your stylesheet:

```
.leaf5:hover .cashdup-text {
    opacity:0;        
}
.cashdup-text {
  opacity:1;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is when you apply `hover` to your `leaf5` div it displays the `cashdup-text` which then increases the area of `leaf5` including the text part. That is why when you have text displayed you can't make it disappear. Because you are already hovering it.

You can try absolute position like this way:

CSS:

```
.cashdup-text {
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 22px;  
}
.cashdup-text{
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
.leaf5:hover .cashdup-text {
    display: block;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dqz9j2tj/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, `.cashdup-text` is a child of `.leaf5` so when you're hovering over `.cashdup-text`, the browser sees it that you're also hovering over `.leaf5` (in a way).

Are you open to using JS? If so, please see below.

```js
var showme = document.getElementById("showme");
showme.style.display = "none";
function display() {
  showme.style.display = "block";
  }
function hide() {
  showme.style.display = "none";
  }
```

```html
<div class="leaf5" onMouseOver="display();" onMouseOut="hide();">
    <img class="leaf-5-about" src="images/Leaf%205%20about.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/Leaf%205%20about%20hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/Leaf%205%20about.png'">
</div>
<div class="cashdup-info">
    <h3 class="cashdup-text" id="showme"><i><span style="font-size: 38px; color: #359869" >CashdUp</span> is a home budgeting tool that allows you to make every cent count. </i></h3>
</div>
```

As you can see, I've added an `id` of "showme" to the `h3` element you want to show / hide and have added `MouseOver` / `MouseOut` events to the `.leaf5` div. I've also separated `.leaf5` from the div below, just so it doesn't cause any issues like you described when hovering over `.cashdup-text`.

Comment: I know very little about JS. Though it is on the to do list. How do I go about implementing that into the HTML?

Comment: @cbevans001 You mean, how do you actually add the JS to a web page? You could add the above JS into <script> tags within your page, or add it to an external JS file and link to your page... Here's a good synopsis: [http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/incorporate](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/incorporate)

Comment: @cbevans001 I noticed you'd used `onmouseover` / `onmouseout` on your image, that's why I thought you'd be open to using JS.

Comment: I used it because that's the only way I could figure out how to get my page to do what I wanted it to do. Regardless of if it's the correct way. Still new to all of this.